# identity not created with fluent configuration entity framework on guid

Tags: entity-framework-5, entity-framework-6, entity-framework-migrations

I had a curious case of entity framework migration and database generated guid column .

```
public class ErrorLogs
{
    public Guid ErrorLogsId { get; set; }
    public Int64 Sequence { get; set; }        
}
```

This is the class which has two identity columns . One is guid and another is sequence . However the case is I have configured the entity framework based on fluent configurations in `OnModelCreating` method .

I have defined the convention for primary here . as

```
builder.Properties().Where(x => x.Name == x.DeclaringType + "Id").Configure(config =>
        {
            config.IsKey().HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity);
        });

        builder.Properties().Where(x => x.Name == "Sequence" && x.PropertyType == typeof(Int64)).Configure(x =>
        {
            x.HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity);                
        });
```

Now the interesting thing is . While I generate the migration . The int column shows its identity . but the migration file doesnt have the identity option on `Guid` column.
But accordingly for the convention which I mentioned on `OnModelCreating` method it should have generated the migration file with identity parameter on `Guid` column .  Can tell me anybody why its happening ?

One more note . IF i use `EntityTypeConfiguration<ErrorLogs>` and provide them as 
`builder.Configurations.Add(new ErrorLogsMappingMap());` then its able to create the identity column for guid as well . But not in case of global fluent Entity  configuration convention .

The migration file is generated as :

```
 CreateTable(
            "REMS.ErrorLogs",
            c => new
                {
                    ErrorLogsId = c.Guid(nullable: false),
                    Sequence = c.Long(nullable: false, identity: true)                      
                })
            .PrimaryKey(t => t.ErrorLogsId);
```

But here in the file actually it should have been `ErrorLogsId = c.Guid(nullable: false,identity:true),`